# How to add hamburger button in angular material sidenav

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I already found this template in plunker but the sidenav disappears when the screen is 600 px or less, how do I add hamburger button to show and hide the sidenav menu?

http://embed.plnkr.co/d3zExiS03YNOMLHdfEIj/preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I changed a little bit ***home.view.html*** and ***home.controller.js*** I think I made it how you want.

```
<div layout="row">
  <section layout="column" layout-fill>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z1" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
      <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools" md-scroll-shrink>
        <h3>My App Title</h3>
        <md-button aria-label="Close" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="vm.toggleMenu()" hide-gt-sm>
            X
        </md-button>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content role="navigation">
        <ul class="side-menu">
          <li ng-repeat="section in vm.menu.sections" class="parent-list-item"
              ng-class="{'parentActive' : vm.isSectionSelected(section)}">
            <h2 class="menu-heading" ng-if="section.type === 'heading'"
                id="heading_{{ section.name | nospace }}">
              {{section}}
            </h2>
            <menu-link section="section" ng-if="section.type === 'link'"></menu-link>
            <menu-toggle section="section" ng-if="section.type === 'toggle'"></menu-toggle>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-toolbar hide-gt-sm>
        <md-button aria-label="Menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="vm.toggleMenu()">
            <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path fill="currentColor" d="M3,6H21V8H3V6M3,11H21V13H3V11M3,16H21V18H3V16Z" />
            </svg>
        </md-button>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content flex>
      <ui-view name="content"></ui-view>
    </md-content>
  </section>
</div>
```

and

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myMenuApp.controllers')

.controller('HomeCtrl', [
      '$rootScope',
      '$log',
      '$state',
      '$timeout',
      '$location',
      'menu',
      '$mdSidenav', 
      '$mdUtil',
      function ($rootScope, $log, $state, $timeout, $location, menu, $mdSidenav, $mdUtil) {

        var vm = this;
        var aboutMeArr = ['Family', 'Location', 'Lifestyle'];
        var budgetArr = ['Housing', 'LivingExpenses', 'Healthcare', 'Travel'];
        var incomeArr = ['SocialSecurity', 'Savings', 'Pension', 'PartTimeJob'];
        var advancedArr = ['Assumptions', 'BudgetGraph', 'AccountBalanceGraph', 'IncomeBalanceGraph'];

        function isOpen(section) {
          return menu.isSectionSelected(section);
        };

        function toggleOpen(section) {
          menu.toggleSelectSection(section);
        };

        //handler to open/close a SideNav; when animation finishes report completion in console
        function buildToggler(navID) {
          return $mdUtil.debounce(function () {
            $mdSidenav(navID).toggle();
          }, 300);
        };

        //functions for menu-link and menu-toggle
        vm.isOpen = isOpen;
        vm.toggleOpen = toggleOpen;
        vm.autoFocusContent = false;
        vm.menu = menu;

        vm.status = {
          isFirstOpen: true,
          isFirstDisabled: false
        };

        vm.toggleMenu = buildToggler('left');

      }])
})();
```

Comment: I owe you one , this code you did really helped me a lot , you have saved me many days of effort, thank you very much for your work , this will help me in my job

Comment: I'm glad it helped